# How to map Enum property in Entity Framework 6 Code First and Fluent Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, code-first, ef-fluent-api

I've been searching the internet how to map enum in ASP.NET MVC project using Entity Framework 6 (Code First and Fluent Api), the results of my search showed that this type of mapping is not trival as in we do in Java (Hibernate + JPA) .

I found an article that gives an idea of how to solve the problem, but do not know if there is another way.

Article: http://eliot-jones.com/2015/03/entity-framework-enum

They could share experience on this type of mapping?

What would be the correct or official way to map Enum?

I'm working with the possibility that the field is string in the database and for this reason I would like to know if you can work with the ordinal type or the name of the enumeration.

I wait for a return and I thank you for your attention.

Comment: Why don't you just map it to an int field in your db?

Comment: You don't even need to do that, just map it as normal and as long as the db field type is the same as the underlying enum type (byte, short, int etc...) it'll work fine.

Comment: You do not have to do anything. Your model has a property of that enum type, just map it as you would any other property. Make sure you specify the enum type though if it is not an int like when using a byte, short, int, or a long. The database will then automatically have that column be the same type as the enum (tinyint, smallint, int, bigint).

Comment: The question may be what you need in the DB can you accept an `int` as prev comments state or maybe you are working with some existing schema and must map to string/characters. Please provide more information

Comment: I believe you have your answer (your edit did not really provide anything new). One other note on your edit, a string can not be an underlying enum type (not in c# anyways). I would recommend you try it and if you get stuck come back with a specific question. There is not much else anyone can do for you as the answer is quit simple (I would not know how else to elaborate on it without just writing the code for you).

Comment: I'm working with the possibility that the field is string in the database and for this reason I would like to know if you can work with the ordinal type or the name of the enumeration.

Comment: A string will not work out of the box. You would have to handle the conversion between string and enum in the model and map the string. There is no concept of ordinal in c# for an enum. Each item in an enum has a value starting at 0 and incrementing from there however you can also explicitly assign values in the enum declaration so you could make it start at 4 or you can assign each enum item its own value and do so in any order you wish.

Comment: Might also be worth looking into Jimmy Bogard's enum class pattern; a little more akin to Java's enumerations. You can map these really well with EF using the fluent API and it allows you to encapsulate any enum related business rules / logic into the class itself https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/